# ImportError: cannot import name 'MyClass' from "myFile.py", without restarting the notebook

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, import

Using VSCode, I have a file `myFile.py` with a class `myClass`

```
# myFile.py
class myClass(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
         super(myClass, self).__init__())
         self.a = 1
```

No in a JupyterNotebook `someNb.ipynb` inside the same folder as `myFile.py` I just want to import `myClass` in a python cell:

```
from myFile import myClass
```

However, even though I am saving both files (as stated in other questions), I get the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'myClass' from 'myFile' (<path-to-myFile.py>)
```

I also tried to add

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 24
```

before `from myFile import myClass`, but also this does not see the changes in `myFile.py`.

Note: When I reopen the notebook it works. And `<path-to-myFile.py>` is the correct path.

So the issue is more: Why do I need to reopen the whole notebook everytime I am making changes to `myFile.py`? I just want to make changes to `myFile.py`, save both `someNb.ipynb` and `myFile.py`, and import the new changes (classes), without reloading the notebook and loosing all variables.

Comment: Are you certain that the path in the error message matches where you actually have the `myFile.py` file? Are you certain that its name is actually `myFile.py`, and not e.g. `myFile.py.txt`? (Keep in mind that Windows may be hiding file extension from you.) What happens if you just try `import myFile`? What happens if you try to *run* that file? Is there still a problem if you *don't* use a Jupyter notebook, and just import from another ordinary Python file? Why do you think that VSCode is relevant to the problem - did you try to run the code in other ways, for example from the command line?

Comment: Check your file structure and what folder you open with vscode as workspace. If possible, add more detailed error messages.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I think it's an VSCode issue because I already imported other classes from `myFile`. But once i updated it and added another classes and tried to import it in the notebook, it doesnt work anymore. When I reopen the jupyter notebook it works. But I dont want to reopen the notebook, everytime I make changes to `myFile`.

Comment: Even `<path-to-myFile.py>` is the correct path to the file. So that is why I was wondering why, even though its 1. the correct path and 2. all files are saved, it cant import the new class from the file.

Comment: @JialeDu I updated the question to describe that it's not the issue of not finding the file. But more of why VSCode is not directly seeing the changes once I save both files and try to import the new class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73822942/19133920), this is the mechanism of jupyter.

If it is modified in an external file (such as a python file), the change will not be recognized in jupyter. Because this module is already imported after opening jupyter for the first time and running the code, the interpreter kernel already exists this module.

So if you want the jupyter kernel to notice the change, you have to restart jupyter.

[image]