# VScode - code changes not reflected in performance, despite saving

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[image]

Hey everyone!

Just moved over to VScode and dealing with some initial transition problems.

I'm using VScode for Python and have been using the interactive window and debugger. For my python interpreter, I've been selecting Python 3.9.7, which is a part of my Anaconda installation.

I've noticed that when I've been changing and saving my functions in one py file, and then calling the function from another file, that the changes I've made in my code aren't reflected in the code output.

It's worth noting that when the changes are made and saved in a file, and the same file is run, the changes WILL be reflected, so it's purely an issue between files. I reload the functions from the file after I make the changes and save them, so it's not an issue of reloading the function.

To provide some context in the photo, I have different functions in the file "Metric_Functions.py". I'm testing the code using different tests in the file "UnitTestCode.py". However, as I'm running the tests (reloading the functions and running the cell with the specific test), I noticed that when I made updated in the file "Metric_Functions", those changes were not being reflected in the unit test results.

Any help/experience with this kind of issue/suggestions of where to start to look would be really appreciated! Really inexperienced with VScode, so any help would be awesome.

Thanks!

Comment: How are you importing the module where the change is made? Are you doing it in a notebook? When changes are made in an external module the notebook has to be restarted to refresh the namespace.

Comment: If it's not in a notebook then try deleting the `__pycache__` folder.

Comment: how do you `reload the functions`, don't use the interactive python and see if that solves the problem

Comment: I import the functions using "from <file name> import <function name>". I tried deleting the __pycache__ folder; however, the issue is still persisting.

I'm a little unclear on if I'm using a notebook (really sorry for the inexperience). I open the py files from the explorer tab and then edit them within my workspace. I'm unclear if that's considered a notebook, and how to restart it if that's the case.

Comment: @pavel, you were correct, I did need to restart the Jupyter kernel to reflect the changes made in the external module. Thank you for the comment! If you could put the comment as an answer submission, I can mark it as the answer. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iPython and Jupyter imported modules persist throughout the session. If a module has already been imported then running the import statement again doesn't do anything at all since the interpreter can see that this module already exists in the namespace.

In order for the changes to external module to be seen in iPython/Jupyter you need to kill/restart the current instance and then run the import again.